# Unable to read xlsb file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsb

I am trying to read an xlsb file from local using pandas' read_excel but I am getting error.
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.read_excel('a.xlsb', engine = 'pyxlsb')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-06db88cb2446> in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_excel('a.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, parse_cols, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skip_footer, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    348 
    349     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 350         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    351 
    352     return io.parse(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    644             engine = 'xlrd'
    645         if engine not in self._engines:
--> 646             raise ValueError("Unknown engine: {engine}".format(engine=engine))
    647 
    648         # could be a str, ExcelFile, Book, etc.

ValueError: Unknown engine: pyxlsb
```

It works fine for csv and xlsx files.

python version: `3.5.2` 
pandas version: `0.24.2`

Comment: you need to upgrade to pandas 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the problem a bit more and referring to @Datanovice 's comment, it works for me if I update to pandas v1.0.
I am using ubuntu 16.04 which can automatically update my python to 3.5, not any further and pandas v1.0 is supported from python 3.6. Hence, even after updating with the latest versions, I was not able to run the code.
We can install python 3.6 and install pandas v1.0 for that.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Using pandas 3.6, we can simply pass the engine as pyxlsb to read_excel to read the file.

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.read_excel('a.xlsb', engine = 'pyxlsb')
```

Reference to install python3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Answer (score 3):

First install pyxlsb and run the below code.After running the code, you'll have your data stored in df1.

```
pip install pyxlsb

import pandas as pd
from pyxlsb import open_workbook

df=[]
with open_workbook('some.xlsb') as wb:
    with wb.get_sheet(1) as sheet:
        for row in sheet.rows():
            df.append([item.v for item in row])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0])
```

Comment: pandas has a read_excel method which can do the same thing in one line. Just that version v1.0.1 or later is required for it.