# Issues while reading .xlsb file in python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsb

I am facing below issue while reading .xlsb file using `pd.read_excel`

```
df = pd.read_excel('path.xlsb',engine='pyxlsb')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-d18a69e21482>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel('D:/Praneeth/Bot_Factory/File_rename/FCR_Sample_input_file.xlsb',engine='pyxlsb')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 177, in wrapper
    if old_arg_value is not None:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 177, in wrapper
    if old_arg_value is not None:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 307, in read_excel

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 369, in __init__

ValueError: Unknown engine: pyxlsb

Python version : 3.6.5
pandas version : 1.0.1 / 1.0.3 (faced same issue with both versions)
```

Comment: This seems like a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152337/unable-to-read-xlsb-file-using-pandas

Comment: im not able to comment over there, so raised a new question.

Comment: the command given there doesnt work with python 3.6.5

Comment: Makes, sense, can you `import pyxlsb`?

Comment: yes, i can..
i also tried to read using pyxlsb package too.. 
with open_xlsb('D:/Praneeth/Bot_Factory/File_rename/FCR_Sample_input_file.xlsb') as wb:
    for sheetname in wb.sheets:
        print(sheetname)
Error: BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: I tried to replicate using the exact same versions for pandas and python and both worked perfectly, the only think I can think of is that old panda module is still loaded, what is the out of `import pandas as pd` `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: pandas version is 1.0.0

Comment: pls let me know which version of pyxlsb you are using

Comment: I used `pyxlsb==1.0.6`